# get_template_directory() vs bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) vs TEMPLATEPATH

Tags: directory, customization, bloginfo

I was reading this article: [Common WordPress Development Mistakes and How to Fix Them](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/common-wordpress-development-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them/), and in it, they author says:

> Getting the theme location: If you are using TEMPLATEPATH or bloginfo(
>   'template_directory'). **Stop!** You should be using the very useful
>   get_template_directory() as seen in my examples above.

But he doesn't elaborate. What's so bad about `bloginfo()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make a long story short: `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` and `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )` simply return `get_template_directory_uri()`.

So, you can shortcut that second call simply by referring directly to the latter template tag.

[Refer to source for `get_bloginfo()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L400).

A few others:

- `'url'` => `home_url()`
- `'wpurl'` => `site_url()`
- `'stylesheet_url'` => `get_stylesheet_uri()`
- `'stylesheet_directory'` => `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`
- `'locale'` => `get_locale()`

#### Edit

Note also: [`TEMPLATEPATH` and `STYLESHEETPATH` are slated for deprecation](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298), so you are better off simply replacing them now, with `get_template_directory()` and `get_stylesheet_directory()`, respectively.

#### Edit 2

Re: this comment

> Just what I was about to say :). I'd add that `get_template_directory()` returns the path and `get_template_directory_uri()` the url. So the author isn't being consistent: `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` and `get_template_directory()` return different things!

Refer back to source :)

```
case 'template_directory':
case 'template_url':
    $output = get_template_directory_uri();
    break;
```

Re: this comment:

> The one caveat when developing child themes you'll need to use `get_stylesheet_directory()` explicitly. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

True, but that's always been the case. `get_bloginfo()` doesn't return *anything* related to `get_stylesheet_directory()`. It only returns `get_stylesheet_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Comment: The one caveat when developing child themes you'll need to use get_stylesheet_directory() explicitly. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder why WP has so many of these functions that just call another function, that we are then supposed to not use...

Comment: In this case, I think that the reason is simply to maintain backward compatibility to the `get_bloginfo()` parameters.