# bloginfo('template_directory') img src

Tags: templates, directory, bloginfo

I am lazy loading some images with URLs which are added via custom fields.

The lazy load plugin I'm using requires a place-holder image in the `src` attribute and the actual image in data-original.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

I need the image height and width as well, so I've been using `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`.

My problem is using `bloginfo('template_directory')` to get the place-holding image.

The first image here doesn't show the place-holder images but does output the url to the page.

```
    <?php   

        $attch_id_1 = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img1', true));
        $image_attributes_1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attch_id_1, 'full'); 

        $attch_id_2 = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img2', true));
        $image_attributes_2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attch_id_2, 'full');

        $attch_id_3 = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img3', true));
        $image_attributes_3 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attch_id_3, 'full');

        echo '<img src="'.bloginfo('template_directory').'"/images/img-BG.png" data-original="'.$image_attributes_1[0].'">';

        echo '<img src="http://localhost/wordpress-cd/wp-content/themes/cd/images/img-BG.png" data-original="'.$image_attributes_2[0].'">';

        echo '<img src="http://localhost/wordpress-cd/wp-content/themes/cd/images/img-BG.png" data-original="'.$image_attributes_3[0].'">';

    ?>
```

The source for the page looks like this.

`http://localhost/wordpress-cd/wp-content/themes/cd<img src="/images/img-BG.png"`

Why can't I use `bloginfo('template_directory')` here?

How can I output the images correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `bloginfo()` while your are outputting using `echo` because bloginfo it self also out puts string using `echo`.  Below will work for you, you also have extra double quote which i have removed....

```
<?php   

        $attch_id_1 = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img1', true));
        $image_attributes_1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attch_id_1, 'full'); 

        $attch_id_2 = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img2', true));
        $image_attributes_2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attch_id_2, 'full');

        $attch_id_3 = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img3', true));
        $image_attributes_3 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attch_id_3, 'full');

        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/img-BG.png" data-original="'.$image_attributes_1[0].'">';

        echo '<img src="http://localhost/wordpress-cd/wp-content/themes/cd/images/img-BG.png" data-original="'.$image_attributes_2[0].'">';

        echo '<img src="http://localhost/wordpress-cd/wp-content/themes/cd/images/img-BG.png" data-original="'.$image_attributes_3[0].'">';

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$so97086_template_directory = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
```

And replace

```
bloginfo('template_directory') with $so97086_template_directory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that get_template_directory_uri() is preferred over get_bloginfo('template_directory').

Please refer to this for more information: [get_template_directory() vs bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) vs TEMPLATEPATH](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72727/get-template-directory-vs-bloginfo-template-directory-vs-templatepath)