# Return child theme url

Tags: functions, child-theme

I'm trying to return the child theme url for a child theme favicon. The official code to use in this case is:

```
//* Display a custom favicon
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_load_favicon', 'sp_favicon_filter' );
function sp_favicon_filter( $favicon_url ) {
    return 'http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/images/favicon.ico';
}
```

but adding absolute urls stresses me out ;)

I know that

```
get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')
```

returns the correct url, so how do I get that into the 'return'?

I've tried

```
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_load_favicon', 'bg_favicon_filter' );
function bg_favicon_filter( $favicon_url ) {
    $stylesheet_dir_uri = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
    $stylesheet_uri = $stylesheet_dir_uri . "/images/favicon.ico";
    return  '$stylesheet_dir';
}
```

but I'm out my depth here

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you putting apostrophe in return statement?

Comment: because I'm still learning, sorry - it was a mistake, I'll do better next time I promise ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function to use here is [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri). Please feel free to read [this useful post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72731/31545) by @ChipBennet regarding this issue

Your use of syntax is also wrong in your return statement as already pointed out. A variable is php, not html, therefore you don't need the single quotes which are used to wrap html in a mixed string.

You can simply just use the following as your return statement

```
return get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/favicon.ico';
```

Comment: Excellent thanks Pieter, that is perfect, you are a legend :). Thanks also for explaining my syntax error, it's very helpfull

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped. Enjoy :-)